# escape_javascript is removing angle brackets - Solutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping

I am outfitting a rails 3 app (version 3.0.9) to use AJAX and jQuery to fluidly handle user posts. I would like for a #users_info div to be refreshed following the post submission. I can get this to work, but the contents of the div don't render properly. Specifically, the jquery code in create.js.erb:

```
 $("#right_bar").html(
'<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/user_info') %>'
 );
```

Results in the user info div outputting:

```
 <div id=user_info> <h1>    
 <a href=/users/101>Example Usera> h1>  
 46 posts <br>  
 4 discussions <br> 
 Following 2 topics <br>    
 Joined 8 days ago.div>
```

Note how the escape_javascript function removes all leading angle brackets on end tags in html ( becomes a>,  become h1>). How can I force the escape_javascript to avoid doing so? I think this is all the relevant code, but can post more if needed.

UPDATE

I was wondering if maybe using to_json would be part of the solution. the code:

<%= escape_javascript((render :partial => 'shared/user_info').to_json) %>

results in the html tags not being destroyed. However, i don't know how to convert back from json to output the desired html. Just thought this might be the right start, but i'm not sure how to finish it

Comment: You mean it's removing the leading angle brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. just wrap the contents of escape_javascript(contents) in escape_javascript("#{}").

```
 $("#right_bar").html(
'<%= (escape_javascript("#{(render :partial => 'shared/user_info')}")).html_safe %>'
 );
```

I added the html_safe at the end so that rails would not make the angle brackets literal. Now the html tags go through properly, and everything renders properly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably on an older version of rails. A release earlier in June caused this problem. Make sure to upgrade to the current release in the branch you're on (2.3.12, 3.0.9, or 3.1.0.rc4) and it should work.

Comment: using version 3.0.9 -- do i need to update a specific gem to do with escape_javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#right_bar").html(
   "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/user_info') %>"
);
```